# Entity Framework one-to-one relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having some issues with understanding how to property set up one-to-one relationships for a Web API using Entity Framework Core.

Consider the following objects:

```
public class Car
{  
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Int32 CarId { get; set; }

    public virtual Horn Horn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

public class Horn
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Int32 HornId { get; set; }
    public Sound Sound { get; set; }
}

public class Sound
{
    // some other props
}
```

When I perform a query in my repository, one-to-many is by default excluded unless I use `.Include()`, however, for one-to-one properties, they are by default included when I serialize.

e.g. It gets really messy because I query for a car and it returns all it's sub-components in the JSON response.

I can set `car.Horn = null`, etc, but that seems difficult to maintain for complex objects. I would like it to function like `.Include()`, but by default be excluded (in case I do want to query the full object).

Edit: Note, this issue is recursive, the car pulls in horn which pulls in sound. On a real world example like a user table, the automatically pulled in data when serialized is huge unless specifically nullifying the child properties.

EDIT2:

Here is an example of a repository call that by default bring back all one-to-one properties:

`var group = _context.Car.Include(c => 
         c.Wheels).SingleOrDefault(u => u.CarId == id);`

Note the Include works as expected for many-to-one, but this query, even when the Include is removed, will recursively return all child objects that are one-to-one.

It does appear some type of lazy loading is being introduced in EF CORE 2.1

Comment: Show your configuration of the entities - are you using complex types, table splitting?

Comment: Are you using EF Core or?

Comment: I am using EF Core, simple entities with relationships on the primary key.

Comment: It doesn't happen in the latest EFC 2.0. What EFC version are you on? Also you need to provide [mcve].

Comment: I am using EF CORE 2.0:

Comment: Well, according to your EDIT 2, you are using some sort of a prelease EFC 2.1 build. I don't think asking a questions for not released software is correct and just wastes our time.

Comment: There's no need to be rude. I never said I was using 2.1 or a pre-release. I am using EF Core 2.0.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude. My first comment started with *It doesn't happen in the latest EFC 2.0*. I'm not saying that you don't have an issue, just the issue is not reproducible with the information provided, so you need to provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This article should give you a hint. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx
Mainly:

> Turn lazy loading off for serialization
>
> Lazy loading and serialization don’t mix well, and if you aren’t
>   careful you can end up querying for your entire database just because
>   lazy loading is enabled. Most serializers work by accessing each
>   property on an instance of a type. Property access triggers lazy
>   loading, so more entities get serialized. On those entities properties
>   are accessed, and even more entities are loaded. It’s a good practice
>   to turn lazy loading off before you serialize an entity. The following
>   sections show how to do this.

EDIT:
Here is the way to disable lazy loading for all entities. But note you have to achieve this several way, so check the other options in the article...

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public YourContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Show how you turn it off and then it could be a valid answer.

Comment: Lazy loading is not supported in EF Core

Comment: Yes, this would be valid only for classic EF

Comment: It's too bad this doesn't work in EF Core - this is similar to what I'm looking for. This problem becomes much worse when it's a larger table with many one-to-one tables, such as a "user" table. Unless nullified, even the child tables bring in the one-to-one child relationships off those tables, so it's recursive!!

Answer (score 0):

Context mapping

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<SessionFeedbackModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(s => s.Session).WithOne(p => p.Feedback)
                .HasForeignKey<SessionFeedbackModel>(s => s.SessionId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SessionQuestionModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(e => e.SessionResult).WithOne(e => e.SessionQuestion)
                .HasForeignKey<SessionQuestionResultModel>(e => e.SessionQuestionId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        });
```

Models

```
   public class SessionQuestionResultModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int SessionQuestionId { get; set; }

        public SessionQuestionModel SessionQuestion { get; set; }
    }


    public class SessionFeedbackModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SessionId { get; set; }

        public SessionModel Session { get; set; }

    }
```

EF Core 1.x or 2.x does not support 1 to 1 very well or at all, but it can be done this way, this would be radically different for EF 6.x.x